# Is there a reliable method to extract and display links from a Google search result page in an Android textView using web scraping in Java?

Tags: java, android, web-scraping

**My need:** I want to extract the links of websites that appear on Google search result page and display them in a textView. The Google search may vary according to user's needs.
Purpose of this (app) is to get the most related, nearest results for the user.

The mechanism is when the user inputs their search words and clicked on the button, the links that are extracted should be appeared on the textView.
**Errors:** I don't get an error in the code or any results on the textView.

**My Question:** Where have I gone wrong? How can I correct it? Is there any other way to do this?

TestHomeFragment.java

```
public class TestHomeFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageButton b_search;
    TextView search_webview;
    String userLocation = "Sri Lanka";
    TextView textView;
    List<String> sriLankanUrls;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_home_fragment, container, false);

// --------------------------- Search Mechanism -----------------------------------------//
        sriLankanUrls = new ArrayList<>();

        b_search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String searchQuery="buy "+et_search.getText().toString()+ " in " + userLocation ;
                new GoogleSearchScraperTask().execute();
            }
        }); return view;
    }
    private class GoogleSearchScraperTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, StringBuilder> {

        @Override
        protected StringBuilder doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            StringBuilder resultBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            try {
                // Specify the Google search query
                String searchQuery="buy "+et_search.getText().toString()+ " in " + userLocation ;

                // Fetch the search results page
                Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.com/search?q=" + searchQuery).get();

                // Extract sentences containing "https://"
                Elements searchResults = doc.select("div.g");
                for (Element result : searchResults) {
                    String snippet = result.select("span.st").text();

                    if (snippet.contains("http")) {
                        resultBuilder.append(snippet).append("\n");
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }return resultBuilder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(StringBuilder resultBuilder) {
            super.onPostExecute(resultBuilder);

            // Set the scraped sentences in the TextView
            textView.setText(resultBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```